# Work flow did not run when new item is created

Tags: sharepoint

I have a workflow that is set to start automatically when an item is created or changed.
It has a form that it uses (xx.xsn* and the type is:  Initiation)

I can go to the sharepoint website and the document library associated with this workflow and upload a file (this effectively creates a new item).  This action initiated the workflow and allows it to run.

I also have an asp.net web that can create a new item (but it does not upload a file like the manual step above).  However, the workflow does not run.  Is it a permission issue because it is created externally or something else?

The workflow is very simple, just sending out email.